# MSE consistency of Bayes Estimators

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I was wondering if anyone could direct me to a general result regarding the consistency of Bayesian Estimators (I assume MSE consistency is used but I don't know)? I can't find anything, I would if possible prefer a general proof verses something on a specific distribution.

Comment: It is a deep topic.  Try for example 
[Persi Diaconis and David Freedman, On the Consistency of Bayes Estimates](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176349830) or some links from [Cosma Rohilla Shalizi](http://bactra.org/notebooks/bayesian-consistency.html)